# How can perform an update to replace one or more of: ";to " with "; " in a column

Tags: sql-server

I have a [Phrase] table with a column named [English].  The data in this table can look like this:

```
 "zzz; to abc; to def" needs to be changed to: "zzz; abc; def"

 "zzz; to xxx" needs to be changed to: "zzz; xxx"
```

I think I can do this with a regular expression if I was to put this into a string but is there any way that I can do this inside a SET part of an UPDATE?  If not does anyone have another suggestion as to how I could do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [**`REPLACE`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx) function

```
select replace(Yourcolumn,'; to',';') as Replaced_column
From yourtable
```

Comment: need a space after the `;` in the last arguement.

Comment: @scsimon - In sample data after `to` there is a space. so I guess we dont need it in replace

Comment: I see that you don't have a space after your `to`. It looked like you did at first. my apologies.

Answer (score 1):

A simple replace should work. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx

```
REPLACE(YourColumn, '; to ', '; ')
```

Answer (score 1):

REPLACE should do the trick

```
UPDATE Table
SET FieldValue = REPLACE(FieldValue, 'TO ', '')
WHERE....
```

Comment: This mostly works. It will replace all occurrences of 'TO  ' to an empty string so it might get some false positives.